# Pandas - Organizing JSON Data

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON file that I want to organize in a specific format where each ID becomes a row and the other features become columns. Can this transformation be done using Python/pandas? My current code does not output any rows.

**Current JSON format:**

[Raw JSON file surpasses max characters in Stack Overflow, so here's the link to it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1njgXmdy3QHMaMNb_8xD1U_H8euxTM_sC/view?usp=sharing)

**Features to Extract:**

- Departure City
- Departure Date
- Departure Time
- Arrival Location
- Arrival Date
- Arrival Time
- Flight Duration
- Operating Carrier
- Aircraft Type
- Cabin Class
- Fare Class
- Price
- Days Until Departure (1 day, 1 week, 1 month)

**Current Code:** df_json contains JSON file

```
# Extracting data from the JSON structure
data = []

itinerary_groups = df_json["groupedItineraryResponse"]["itineraryGroups"]

for group in itinerary_groups:
    itineraries = group.get("itineraries", [])
    for itinerary in itineraries:
        leg = itinerary.get("legs", [])
        if leg:
            leg = leg[0]
            schedules = leg.get("schedules", [])
            if schedules:
                schedule = df_json["groupedItineraryResponse"]["scheduleDescs"][schedules[0]["ref"] - 1]

                departure_city = schedule["departure"]["city"]
                departure_date = schedule["departure"]["time"].split("T")[0]
                departure_time = schedule["departure"]["time"].split("T")[1]
                arrival_location = schedule["arrival"]["city"]
                arrival_date = schedule["arrival"]["time"].split("T")[0]
                arrival_time = schedule["arrival"]["time"].split("T")[1]
                flight_duration = leg["elapsedTime"]
                operating_carrier = leg["carrier"]["operating"]
                aircraft_type = leg["carrier"]["equipment"]["code"]
                cabin_class = itinerary["passengerInfoList"][0]["fareComponents"][0]["cabinCode"]
                fare_class = itinerary["passengerInfoList"][0]["fareComponents"][0]["fareBasisCode"]
                price = itinerary["totalFare"]["totalPrice"]

                # Calculate "Days Until Departure" based on current date and departure date
                current_date = datetime.now()
                departure_date = datetime.strptime(departure["time"].split("T")[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
                days_until_departure = (departure_date - current_date).days

                data.append([
                    departure_city, departure_date, departure_time,
                    arrival_location, arrival_date, arrival_time,
                    flight_duration, operating_carrier, aircraft_type,
                    cabin_class, fare_class, price, days_until_departure
                ])

# Creating a DataFrame
columns = [
    "Departure City", "Departure Date", "Departure Time",
    "Arrival Location", "Arrival Date", "Arrival Time",
    "Flight Duration", "Operating Carrier", "Aircraft Type",
    "Cabin Class", "Fare Class", "Price", "Days Until Departure"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
```

Comment: Please give us the actual JSON rather than the output of `pd.read_json`.

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure how to override max characters here, so I updated with a link to the JSON file.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what the columns in your desired output are, and how they are linked to each other?

Comment: @Nick Would there be a way to segment the JSON so that all/most features are included, or do I have to choose specific ones? This is related to flights, so it includes features such as fare pricing, departure locations, scheduling, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I see that from the file. But, for example, I don't see why you've tied the first message to the first itinerary?

Comment: @Nick Sorry, I don't quite understand what you're asking. Could you please clarify?

Comment: In the desired result in the original question, you had information from the fist message in the first row, along with information from the first itinerary, and it's not obvious why they are related to each other

Comment: @Nick Sorry, that was a mistake. I just want each itinerary. I updated the question and would like the following features to be extracted.

Comment: better add in question (as text) some small JSON as example and show expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from your original code, and adjusting according to the structure and data in `BCN.json`, this is what I think you need to do:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

with open('BCN.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

schedule_descs = data["groupedItineraryResponse"]["scheduleDescs"]
leg_descs = data["groupedItineraryResponse"]["legDescs"]
itinerary_groups = data["groupedItineraryResponse"]["itineraryGroups"]

out = []
for group in itinerary_groups:
    itineraries = group.get("itineraries", [])
    departure_date = group["groupDescription"]["legDescriptions"][0]["departureDate"]
    departure_location = group["groupDescription"]["legDescriptions"][0]["departureLocation"]
    arrival_date = group["groupDescription"]["legDescriptions"][0].get("arrivalDate", departure_date)
    arrival_location = group["groupDescription"]["legDescriptions"][0]["arrivalLocation"]
    
    # Calculate "Days Until Departure" based on current date and departure date
    current_date = datetime.now()
    departure_date = datetime.strptime(departure_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    days_until_departure = (departure_date - current_date).days
    
    # iterate itineraries
    for itinerary in itineraries:
        legs = itinerary.get("legs", [])
        for leg in legs:
            schedules = leg_descs[leg.get('ref') - 1].get("schedules", [])
            for schedule in schedules:
                schedule_data = schedule_descs[schedule.get('ref') - 1]
                
                departure_time = schedule_data["departure"]["time"].split("+")[0]
                arrival_time = schedule_data["arrival"]["time"].split("+")[0]
                flight_duration = schedule_data["elapsedTime"]
                operating_carrier = schedule_data["carrier"]["operating"]
                aircraft_type = schedule_data["carrier"]["equipment"]["code"]
                cabin_class = itinerary["pricingInformation"][0]["fare"]["passengerInfoList"][0]["passengerInfo"]["fareComponents"][0]["segments"][0]["segment"]["cabinCode"]
                fare_class = itinerary["pricingInformation"][0]["fare"]["passengerInfoList"][0]["passengerInfo"]["fareComponents"][0]["segments"][0]["segment"]["bookingCode"]
                price = itinerary["pricingInformation"][0]["fare"]["totalFare"]["totalPrice"]
                
                # add to output
                out.append([
                    departure_city, departure_date, departure_time,
                    arrival_location, arrival_date, arrival_time,
                    flight_duration, operating_carrier, aircraft_type,
                    cabin_class, fare_class, price, days_until_departure
                ])

# Creating a DataFrame
columns = [
    "Departure City", "Departure Date", "Departure Time",
    "Arrival Location", "Arrival Date", "Arrival Time",
    "Flight Duration", "Operating Carrier", "Aircraft Type",
    "Cabin Class", "Fare Class", "Price", "Days Until Departure"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns = columns)
```

Output:

```
   Departure City Departure Date Departure Time Arrival Location Arrival Date
0             AMS     2023-11-15       07:00:00              BCN   2023-11-15  \
1             AMS     2023-11-15       07:00:00              BCN   2023-11-15
2             AMS     2023-11-15       14:55:00              BCN   2023-11-15
3             AMS     2023-11-15       10:25:00              BCN   2023-11-15
4             AMS     2023-11-15       13:30:00              BCN   2023-11-15
5             AMS     2023-11-15       14:55:00              BCN   2023-11-15
6             AMS     2023-11-15       10:25:00              BCN   2023-11-15
7             AMS     2023-11-15       13:30:00              BCN   2023-11-15
8             AMS     2023-11-15       16:30:00              BCN   2023-11-15
9             AMS     2023-11-15       16:30:00              BCN   2023-11-15
10            AMS     2023-11-15       19:25:00              BCN   2023-11-15
11            AMS     2023-11-15       19:25:00              BCN   2023-11-15
12            AMS     2023-11-15       08:15:00              BCN   2023-11-15
13            AMS     2023-11-15       10:05:00              BCN   2023-11-15
14            AMS     2023-11-15       14:25:00              BCN   2023-11-15
15            AMS     2023-11-15       16:55:00              BCN   2023-11-15
16            AMS     2023-11-15       20:55:00              BCN   2023-11-15

   Arrival Time  Flight Duration Operating Carrier Aircraft Type Cabin Class
0      09:15:00              135                VY           32A           Y  \
1      09:15:00              135                VY           320           Y
2      17:10:00              135                VY           32A           Y
3      12:40:00              135                VY           320           Y
4      15:45:00              135                VY           320           Y
5      17:10:00              135                VY           320           Y
6      12:40:00              135                VY           32A           Y
7      15:45:00              135                VY           32A           Y
8      18:45:00              135                VY           320           Y
9      18:45:00              135                VY           32A           Y
10     21:40:00              135                VY           32A           Y
11     21:40:00              135                VY           320           Y
12     10:25:00              130                KL           73J           Y
13     12:15:00              130                KL           73H           Y
14     16:35:00              130                KL           73H           Y
15     19:05:00              130                KL           73H           Y
16     23:05:00              130                KL           73H           Y

   Fare Class  Price  Days Until Departure
0           A  231.4                    -7
1           V  242.4                    -7
2           N  256.4                    -7
3           F  268.4                    -7
4           F  268.4                    -7
5           F  268.4                    -7
6           S  269.4                    -7
7           S  269.4                    -7
8           L  281.4                    -7
9           V  282.4                    -7
10          I  478.4                    -7
11          B  524.4                    -7
12          Y  825.0                    -7
13          Y  825.0                    -7
14          Y  825.0                    -7
15          Y  825.0                    -7
16          Y  825.0                    -7
```